# Anyway to UNION 3 columns with 2 in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("""(SELECT DISTINCT game_id,winner as player_name from chess_wc_history_game_info WHERE winner!='draw' GROUP BY game_id,event,winner)
    UNION
    ((SELECT game_id, player as player_name FROM chess_wc_history_moves WHERE black_queen_count=0 AND color='Black')
    UNION
    (SELECT game_id, player as player_name FROM chess_wc_history_moves WHERE white_queen_count=0 AND color='White'))""").show()
```

This outputs:

```
|             game_id|         player_name|
| -------------------|--------------------|
|61b784cc-cdab-496...|        Morozevich,A|
|39a6b655-19d8-419...|     Karpov, Anatoly|
|a744139e-aff8-4d3...|         Tal, Mihail|
|e945781f-92a2-4fb...|        Sargissian,G|
|f9307e55-3eff-477...|            Adams,Mi|
|0230130d-ee51-4f9...|     Barua, Dibyendu|
|3d34d86e-216e-41f...|    Tiviakov, Sergei|
```

Expected Output:

```
|             game_id|         player_name|event          |
| -------------------|--------------------|---------------|
|61b784cc-cdab-496...|        Morozevich,A|  Event names  |
|39a6b655-19d8-419...|     Karpov, Anatoly|               |
|a744139e-aff8-4d3...|         Tal, Mihail|               |
|e945781f-92a2-4fb...|        Sargissian,G|               |
|f9307e55-3eff-477...|            Adams,Mi|               |
```

Whereas adding the event column which is contained inside the `chess_wc_history_game_info` table makes the query invalid saying UNION can only be performed on two columns whereas first one has 3 columns and second has 2 columns, is there anyway  I can SELECT all 3 at once without changing the results? (game_id,event,winner)

Comment: Just add a null/empty third column to the ones that only have 2.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear.  Something like `select game_id, player, '' as event...`

Comment: @Andrew it is outputting the wrong things, I want the output to be correct and just add the event column display but it just changes the output.

Comment: If you are not strictly constrained to using SQL, you can use `unionByName` with `allowMissingColumns` to `true`

Comment: @ShreyRatna - after re-reading your post, if your desired order of columns is game_id,event,winner, then you would need `select game_id,'' as event , player, ...`

Comment: @Andrew the column values differ from the expected output, even if I do it that way.

Comment: @ShreyRatna, could you please write what do you mean by "values differ from the expected output"? How exactly do they differ? Maybe you can also show data from chess_wc_history_moves, to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

From the names of your tables, it seems that you can get the event name from joining to the `chess_wc_history_game_info` table. See the SQL below for a solution based on this.

However, it also seems that the first `SELECT` statement will have data that overlaps with the second two `SELECT` statements. Do you need to `UNION` any data at all, or can you just select from `chess_wc_history_game_info` and ignore the other table?

This approach uses a LEFT join so that if no matching event info is found, the event will just be null.

```scala
spark.sql(
    """(SELECT DISTINCT game_id,winner as player_name, event from chess_wc_history_game_info WHERE winner!='draw' GROUP BY game_id,event,winner)
    UNION
    ((SELECT m.game_id, player as player_name, event FROM chess_wc_history_moves m LEFT JOIN chess_wc_history_game_info i on m.game_id = i.game_id WHERE black_queen_count=0 AND color='Black')
    UNION
    (SELECT m.game_id, player as player_name, event FROM chess_wc_history_moves m LEFT JOIN chess_wc_history_game_info i on m.game_id = i.game_id WHERE white_queen_count=0 AND color='White'))"""
  ).show()
```